# I can't figure out how to stop the snap back when a user hover's off a background on my site

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I have the keyframes for the animation but I've tried adding a transition, transform and animation on the normal state to ease the animation back but nothing has worked. This is the code for the animation on hover.

```
  .shadow-pop-bl:hover {
  -webkit-animation: shadow-pop-bl 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.470, 0.000, 
  0.745, 0.715) both;
  animation: shadow-pop-bl 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.470, 0.000, 0.745, 0.715) 
  both;
  }

  @keyframes shadow-pop-bl {
  0% {
  box-shadow: 0 0 #c4c8d4, 0 0 #c4c8d4, 0 0 #c4c8d4, 0 0 #c4c8d4, 0 0 
  #c4c8d4, 0 0 #c4c8d4, 0 0 #c4c8d4, 0 0 #c4c8d4;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0) translateY(0);
  transform: translateX(0) translateY(0);
  }
  100% {
  box-shadow: -1px 1px #c4c8d4, -2px 2px #c4c8d4, -3px 3px #c4c8d4, -4px 
  4px #c4c8d4, -5px 5px #c4c8d4, -6px 6px #c4c8d4, -7px 7px #c4c8d4, 
  -8px 8px #c4c8d4;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(8px) translateY(-8px); transform: 
  translateX(8px) translateY(-8px);
  }
  }
```

Comment: Could you possible provide a video or more thorough explanation of the issue, I don't think I understand what is wrong, or what you want fixed.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're only setting the animation on the `:hover` state and you're expecting it to apply when the element is not hovered (when it obviously does not have ***any*** animation set at all).

One way to solve it is to define the animation on the non-hovered element and change it when hovered. But that's overkill for your case.

For this type of (simple) case (on/off animation), setting

- property values **on non-hover** (unless you want to start from default values)
- property values **on hover**
- transition props (`-timing-function`, `-duration`, `-delay`, `-property`) **on non hover**

...is enough. If you want different values for transition props while the element is hovered, specify them in the `:hover` rules, placed after the ones on normal element.

In conclusion, for your case, this was enough:

```css
.shadow-pop-bl {
  transition: box-shadow .42s cubic-bezier(.5,0,.3,1);
}

.shadow-pop-bl:hover {
  box-shadow: 1px 1px #c4c8d4, 2px 2px #c4c8d4, 3px 3px #c4c8d4, 4px 4px #c4c8d4, 
  5px 5px #c4c8d4, 6px 6px #c4c8d4, 7px 7px #c4c8d4, 8px 8px #c0c4d0;
}
```

**Note:** I removed the `translate` not only to simplify the example, but also because it's considered bad UI to change position of element on hover (hovering an area the element leaves results in flickering between hover/not-hover).

```css
.shadow-pop-bl {
  transition: box-shadow .42s cubic-bezier(.5,0,.3,1);
}

.shadow-pop-bl:hover {
  box-shadow: 
  1px 1px #c4c8d4, 2px 2px #c4c8d4, 3px 3px #c4c8d4, 4px 4px #c4c8d4, 
  5px 5px #c4c8d4, 6px 6px #c4c8d4, 7px 7px #c4c8d4, 8px 8px #c4c8d4, 
  9px 9px #c4c8d4, 10px 10px #c4c8d4, 11px 11px #c4c8d4, 12px 12px #c4c8d4, 
  13px 13px #c4c8d4, 14px 14px #c4c8d4, 15px 15px #c4c8d4, 16px 16px #c4c8d4, 
  17px 17px #c4c8d4, 18px 18px #c4c8d4, 19px 19px #c4c8d4, 20px 20px #c0c4d0;
} 

/* rest is irrelevant */
.shadow-pop-bl {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 2rem;
  border: 1px solid #fcfcfc;
  cursor: pointer;
  max-width: 240px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
body, html {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="shadow-pop-bl">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<br></div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I was trying to add the animation on the non-hovered element but the keyframes were throwing it out. Thank you for the lesson and simplifying it for me.@Andrei Gheorghiu